# one app with multiple merchant accounts attached!! apple pay

Tags: ios8, xcode6, stripe-payments, authorize.net, applepay

is it possible with apple pay if my app users want to pay their doctor (doctor can vary for patients) with apple pay?

For Example

A_patient pay to A_Doctor AND B_patient pay to some other doctor on same app basis on application data. And each doctor has own merchant account.

is it possible with apple pay?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A single app can support multiple merchant identifiers, although these are only used to determine which certificate the payment payload should be encrypted with. Your own back end can route the Apple Pay payment token however you'd like - charge it to different merchant accounts, the same merchant accounts, etc.